# Time complexity for an infinte loop

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have understood very little of computing complexities, but can you actually calculate the run-time complexity of a function running infinitely, for eg:

```
for(i = 0;i < 10;i *= 2)
{
    [Algo / Lines of code]
}
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computing Time T(n) and Big-O with an infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733397/computing-time-tn-and-big-o-with-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The run-time complexity depends on a parameter n, e.g. the size of a data set to be processed, and considers how the runtime changes when n changes, but independent of any "technical" constraints, e.g. the speed of the CPU.
Since you algo does not depend on any parameter, but its runtime is always infinite, one cannot determine a run rime complexity for it.