# Determining the Big-O of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to understand what the Big-O is of the code below.

**What the code is supposed to do**

Essentially, I am trying to select a subset (max size = selectionSize) of random nodes and any edges that exists between them. The selection of random nodes is done in the `while` loop. After having done that, I want to select any edges that exist between the selected nodes.

**What I think it is & why**

<s>I think the running time is `O = n^2` where `n=selectionSize`. The reason is: even though I can increase the size of the elements in `nodes` (e.g. make it 10000), I don't believe it can affect the algorithm since I am only looping through the maximum of `selectionSize`. The only reason I am a bit worried that this is wrong is because of the `while` loop, where I select random elements from the list up until I have enough. While this can take quite long (because it is random), I don't think it affects the overall output in terms of time.</s>
***Edit***: ugh on second thoughts... Nevermind... The `nodes` size does affect it (since `node.getNeighbors()`can be at most the size of the `nodes`).. So I think that if the `selectionSize` is equal to the size of `nodes`, the running time is `O=n^2` where `n=size of nodes`.

Any tips/hints would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
// nodes and selectionSize are my input:
int[] nodes = {1,2,3...,1000}; // 1000 elements
int selectionSize = 500; // This can be at most the size of the elements (in this case 1000)

run_algo(nodes, selectionSize);

public void run_algo(int[] nodes, int selectionSize) {
    randomNodesList = {};

    while(randomNodesList < selectionSize) {
        randomNode = selectRandomNode(nodes); // Assume O(1)

        if(!randomNodesList.exists(randomNode)) { // Assume O(1)
            randomNodesList.push_back(randomNode); // Assume O(1)
        }
    }

    foreach(node in randomNodesList) {
        foreach(neighbor in node.getNeighbors()) { // Max. nodes size (in this case 1000)
            if (!randomNodesList.exists(neighbor)) { // Assume O(1)
                AddEdge(node, neighbor); // Takes O(1) time
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @VidorVistrom, thanks for the comment. I've editted my post. If it is still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Really hard to say for the worst case where the random draws out the same index everytime. You could talk about the best case so easily. And that should be linear depending upon the selection size. Because your lookups are constant and n+n is still linear.

Comment: @VidorVistrom Thanks for the insight & tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `selectRandomNode(nodes);` works with replacement (the same node can be picked twice), then the big o is [not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733397/computing-time-tn-and-big-o-with-an-infinite-loop), since you have a probably infinite loop (you can end up picking the same node again and again).

If it works without replacement, then it's `O(n^2)` (in the worst case, every node may be connected to every other node).

---

Notes on selecting without replacement:

- Consider the case when you are given an array of size `n`, say `A` and an empty array, `B`. All the elements in A are unique.
- The task is to fill `B` with `n` elements randomly selected from `A`. It is desired that there should be at least `k` unique elements in `B`.

It can be shown that the probability of having more than `k` unique items increases with increasing `n` (I have added the equations after the plot).

Thus, in practice, the probability of the loop finishing in a single pass (i.e. in less than `n` steps) gets large as the difference in `n` and `k` increases.
It's very intuitive if you think about it, the math is just cherry on the top.

[image]

---

```
def k_numerator(n, k):
    res = 0
    sign = 1
    for i in range(k, 0, -1):
        pow_term = (i ** n)
        comb_term = comb(k, i)
        prod = pow_term * comb_term
        prod = prod * sign
        res = res + prod
        sign = sign * -1
    return res

def p_exactly_k(n, k):
    """ 
    Returns the probability of `B` containing exactly `k` unique elements
    (also see notes above)
    """

    return (comb(n, k) * k_numerator(n, k)) / (n ** n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand this right. But let's break it down:
The *while*-Loop runs "selectionSize"-times best case and worst case n (where n is the amount of nodes)

Therefore the size of randomNodeList is in O(n).
In a simple graph you can have O(n-1) neighbours. So the whole loop must be in O(n^2) (Because of *n* *(n-1))

> axiom is right. It is in fact not possible to find an upper bound for this algorithm. It's nondeterministic. It depends on your random numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight!

Comment: The number of times the while loop runs depends on the implementation of selectRandomNode().