# How can we find the Time Complexity of the Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I want to know about the time complexity of the given code below, I have a doubt it is O of root n

```
i = n, sum = 0
while (i >= 0){
    i /= 2
    sum += i*i*i
}
```

I am really confused can anyone help me out and explain

Comment: This algorithm returns an infinite loop. This answer can help you understand why it doesn't makes sense to calculate time complexity of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733397/computing-time-tn-and-big-o-with-an-infinite-loop

Comment: Yeah I know that, but in our mcq we don't have anything which can be selected due to infinite

Comment: @FeioNedio Perhaps the condition was intended to be `i > 0` instead of `>=`, for an *O(logn)* time algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure you can always use "time" module to roughly get an idea of the complexity. It would go something like this.

import time

start = time.time() # put this before the loop

end = time.time() #put this after the loop

print(end - start) #this gives you evaluation time of your loop

Find evaluation times for different n's and determine the complexity.

Just by looking at it though, your loop gets executed roughly log2(n) times, and inside you have 2 multiplications and one division (so nothing complex). Therefore, I would assume O(log(n)) is a reasonable guess.

Comment: Well, in principle, yes. But, in practice you will not want to measure infinity (or the time it takes for very weakly converging implementations). The types of the language may offer imprecision, but for some fresh ideas maybe visit some displays of the Achilles paradox that nicely demonstrates the problem of halving a number towards zero ... [Achilles and the Tortoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise) which has a link to [a formulation from Zeno of Elea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Zeno:_Achilles_and_the_tortoise)

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The runtime plot of a function whose runtime is O(log n) will look more or less like it's a constant, since log n grows so slowly. In this particular case, the function is so short that it would be difficult to accurately measure the amount of time it spends doing its calculation, and you'd be mostly left with a flat line with a bunch of noise there. While that's a great way to convince yourself that the practical speed of the function is good enough, it's not sufficient to establish the actual growth rate.

Comment: @templatetypedef Alright, it's useless to test runtime in this case, that's a good point. But I'm still right that it is O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm assuming that the code was meant to be written as

```
i = n, sum = 0
while (i > 0) { // <--- Change >= to >
    i /= 2
    sum += i*i*i
}
```

since otherwise the code would be an infinite loop. With this in mind, let's take a look at what this code is doing.

For starters, note that the `sum` variable isn't doing anything that impacts our time complexity. On each iteration, it gets bigger, but we're doing only O(1) work to update it. That means that the time complexity here is going to depend on how many times the loop runs. Notice that, across the different iterations of the loop, the value of `i` will take on the sequence

> n, n / 2, n / 4, n / 8, n / 16, n / 32, ...

and, in particular, on the kth iteration of the loop the value of `i` will be equal to n / 2<sup>k</sup> (ignoring rounding down, which we can safely do here). The question, then, is at what iteration of the loop we end up with n / 2<sup>k</sup> < 1, which is when the loop will stop. Solving, we get that

> n / 2<sup>k</sup> < 1
>
> n < 2<sup>k</sup>
>
> log<sub>2</sub> n < k

So this loop will stop as soon as the number of loop iterations k is greater than log<sub>2</sub> n. This means that we do Θ(log n) loop iterations, of which each iteration does O(1) work, so the total work done is **Θ(log n)**.